# Negative square roots and complex numbers

Tags: complex-numbers

I am doing a quadratic equation which has given me;

$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{-4}}{2}$

I know that $\sqrt{-1}=i$

Is it then okay to assume $\sqrt{-4} = 4i$ ?
Which would make the next step;

$\frac{2\pm 4i}{2}$

The solution writes that the next step of the working out is;

$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{4i^2}}{2}$

I'm not sure how they got that

Comment: $\sqrt{-4} = \sqrt{4}*\sqrt{-1} = 2i$. When taking the square root of negative numbers, you also have to take the square root of the 'length' of the number, if that makes sense to you.

Comment: Please learn to use [MathJax](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) to format your question more legibly. Currently, I am unable to tell what your numerical values mean.

Comment: I tried to edit the formulas to be more readable, but I'm uncertain whether the last formula came out as you wanted it. Is it correct as written? (Once the edit comes through that is)

Comment: $i^2 = -1$, and therefore, $-4 = i^2 \cdot 4 = 4i^2$. That is how they get it. The next step would be that $4i^2 = (2i)^2$, and from there you can conclude that $\sqrt{-4} = \sqrt{(2i)^2} = 2i$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What they did to get the last equation was to just rewrite $-4$ slightly. As you know, we have that $i^2 = -1$, so they rewrote $-4 = 4(-1) = 4i^2$. Then you will get

$\frac{2\pm\sqrt{-4}}{2} = \frac{2\pm \sqrt{4i^2}}{2}$

by substituting $-4$ with $4i^2$.

Answer (score 1):

we know the fact that $ \sqrt{-1}\ = i $ . 
squaring on both sides , we get $ i^2 = -1 $.

multiply by 4 , $ 4i^2 = -4 $ . so we substitute the same in your equation.

as far as you go , it is not correct to write $ \sqrt{-4}\ = 4 i $ . 
 it is correct to write $ \sqrt{-4}\ = 2i $